# Heroku Mongo Url (Copying db from heroku)

Tags: ruby, mongodb, heroku, mongohq

I'm trying to write a script that copys my heroku db to my local db (mongodb), but I dont have a clue what kind of url format this is:

`mongodb://<username>:<password>@lamppost.5.mongolayer.com:10049,lamppost.4.mongolayer.com:10049/<appname>`

Why are there two urls, comma separated?
Does anyone have a working script to share? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format is a [MongoDB Connection String URI](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/) for a replica set.

The two hosts listed are members of the replica set provided as a "seed list" for [connecting to your MongoHQ instance](http://blog.compose.io/speaking-mongodb-replica-set/). Specifying more than one member of the replica set allows for failover -- the MongoDB driver will attempt to connect to the first available member of the seed list in order to discover the current configuration of a replica set.

You can use this URI to connect from Ruby via [`MongoClient.from_uri(uri)`](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/MongoClient.html#from_uri-class_method).